# VBA Concatenate multiple ranges from data dump

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop, concatenation

My goal is to concatenate two ranges of cells with each other and add conditionally one more piece of string, based on files added as sheets to the workbook.

First range starts at cell C2 and ends at the final row of column AF.
The cells to concatenate are always located on the same row and 31 cells to the right.

In case the first two numbers of the original cell >= 22 or <= 04 AND if the cell on the right contains either "DA", "DR", "LA", "LR" or "EG" add " ND" at the end of the new string.
Otherwise if <= 05 AND the right cells contains either "DA", "DR", "LA", "LR" or "EG" add " SV" to the end of it, else add nothing.

What complicates the situation is that the above mentioned For-loops are added on the back of a For-loop to find files to add as data dump into the Workbook. Somehow the For-loop for the concatenate procedure is being skipped completely and I can't figure out why.

```
Sub Get_Files()
'turn off automatic calculations
Application.Calculation = xlManual

Dim objFSO As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim objFile As Object
Dim worksheetName As String
Dim i As Integer, j As Integer, k As Integer, l As Integer
Dim LastRw As Long
Dim x As Workbook, y As Workbook
Dim ws1 As Worksheet, ws2 As Worksheet
Dim newString As String



'Create an instance of the FileSystemObject
Set objFSO = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Get the folder object
Set objFolder = objFSO.GetFolder(Cells(1, 2).Value)
i = 1
'loops through each file in the directory and prints their names and path
For Each objFile In objFolder.files
'print file name
Cells(i + 10, 1) = objFile.Name
'print file last updated
Cells(i + 10, 2) = objFile.DateLastModified


'print file path without xls
If objFile.Name Like "*.xls" Then

    worksheetName = Replace(objFile.Name, ".xls", "")
   
    Set x = Workbooks.Open(objFile.path)
    Set y = ThisWorkbook
    
    'Check if worksheet exists
    
        For j = 1 To y.Worksheets.Count
        If y.Worksheets(j).Name = worksheetName Then
            exists = True
        End If
        Next j
        
        If Not exists Then
            y.Worksheets.Add.Name = worksheetName
        End If
        
        
 
    Set ws1 = x.Sheets(worksheetName)
    Set ws2 = y.Sheets(worksheetName)
    
    
    ws1.Cells.Copy ws2.Cells
    x.Close True
    
    LastRw = ws2.Range("C2").Cells.End(xlDown).Row
    
            For k = 3 To k = LastRw
                For l = 2 To l = 33
                    
                    If Len(ws2.Cells(k + 31, l)) <> 0 Then
                        
                        If Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) = "DA" _
                        Or Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) = "DR" _
                        Or Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) = "LA" _
                        Or Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) = "LR" _
                        Or Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) = "EG" Then
                           
                           If CInt(Trim(Left(ws2.Cells(k, l), 2))) >= 22 _
                           Or CInt(Trim(Left(ws2.Cells(k, l), 2))) <= 4 Then
                           newString = Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) & Trim(ws2.Cells(k, l)) & " ND"
                           
                           Else
                               If CInt(Trim(Left(ws2.Cells(k, l), 2))) <= 5 Then
                               newString = Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) & Trim(ws2.Cells(k, l)) & " SV"
                               Else
                                   newString = Trim(ws2.Cells(k, 1 + 31)) & Trim(ws2.Cells(k, l))
                               End If
                           End If
                            
                        End If
                    Else
                    
                    newString = Trim(ws2.Cells(k, l))
                    
                    End If
                    
                    ws2.Cells(k, l).Value = newString
                    
                    l = l + 1
                    
                Next l
                
                k = k + 1
                
            Next k
    
    ws2.Visible = xlSheetHidden
    
    exists = False
   
End If

i = i + 1
Next objFile


MsgBox "Update complete. Check last update timestamps of files."

ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Access Control").Activate

'turn on automatic calculations
Application.Calculation = xlAutomatic

End Sub
```

Comment: You might need to start with console debugging if you have not been doing so. Use CTRL+G to open the 'immediate window' in the IDE, then add lines like debug.print "whatever" or debug.print i in specific places. these will print to the console while the code runs allowing you to see if execution occurs.

Comment: I would add `debug.print "IF bla true"` after your IF statements in question, and their elses also. The console will indicate which logic is getting triggered. This works great for counters also `debug.print "k = " & k` for instance (or `debug.print "LastRw = " & LastRw` or other things to verify they are what you expect.)

Comment: `For k = 3 To k = LastRw` - this doesn't look right. This should be `For k = 3 to LastRw`. Same with the next line - that should be `For l = 2 to 33`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
For k = 3 To k = LastRw
   For l = 2 To l = 33
```

These two lines are incorrect syntax. When you write `For k = 3 to k = LastRw`, this evaluates to `For k = 3 to False` or `For k = 3 to 0`, so your loop will never run. This needs to be:

```
For k = 3 To LastRw
   For l = 2 To 33
```